# Include multiple components and <div> in if statement in React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to include multiple `components`and `<div>` in `React` under one ´if´ statement. Since `React` only returns one element it requires all `components` and/or `<div>` elements to be wrapped in one `root`  `<div>` element. Tried but still couldn't manage.

I need to have `<Divider>` component and  `<div className="prod-flow">` inside the the conditional statement. This means I need to hide the entire block if the condition is false. Currently `<Divider>` component can't be hidden since it's outside the if statement. Don't want to use same condition twice to validate.

**Tried** : Wrapping all the elements with one `<div>` - didn't work. Wrapping  the entire block with `[]` inside `{}` - didn't work.

```
        <Divider text="PRODABC" className="blue" />
        <div className="prod-flow">
           {supplyProducts(this.state.products).length > 0 &&
             <FlowSettings
               flow={this.state.room.attributes.flow}
               products={supplyProducts(this.state.products)}
               setpointChange={this.handleSetpointChange}
               sumChange={this.handleSumChange} />
           }
        </div>
```

**Need**: Something like

```
return(
   <div>
     <Component1 />
     <div>
     ...
     ...
     </div>

     {supplyProducts(this.state.products).length > 0 &&
     ...
     ... //<Component2 />
     ... //<div>
          //<Component3 />
     ... //</div>
     }
  </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put wrapper on conditional render!

```
return(
   <div>
     <Component1 />
     <div>...</div>
     {supplyProducts(this.state.products).length > 0 &&
       <div> //Wrapper here
         <Component2 />
         <div>...</div>
         <Component3 />
         <div>...</div>
       </div>
     }
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

in your render method do something like this.

```
render () {

   const renderMore = () => (
       <div>
         <Component1/>
         <div></div>
         <Component2/>
       </div>
   );

   return () (
       <div>
       <Component1 />
       <div>
       ...
       ...
       </div>
      {supplyProducts(this.state.products).length > 0 && renderMore()}
   )
}
```